# XSD 1.1 validation as a web service

Tags: java, xml, jersey, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I am able to validate using XSD 1.1 as a standalone java application. 
However when I get the error when I try to use it with Jersey and deploy as war

```
03-Oct-2016 11:01:19.018 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:414)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder._newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:218)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:145)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:213)
    at com.walmart.taxonomy.validator.XMLValidator.getXSDSchema(XMLValidator.java:59)
    at com.walmart.taxonomy.validator.XMLValidator.validate(XMLValidator.java:139)
    at com.walmart.taxonomy.services.ValidationService.validateXML(ValidationService.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchema11Factory could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:403)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:399)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:399)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: W3C_XML_SCHEMA11_NS_URI
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchema11Factory.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 53 more
```

The difference when running as a standalone application vs running as webapp is the content loader. When running as  web app the class loader is org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader while when running as standalone app the loader is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader

Comment: Looks like Tomcat finding conflicting version of xerces lib . Are you packaging your application with xerces lib ? or one from jdk ? If you are using maven make sure you dont have conflicting version.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I have two versions of Xerces one with XSD1.1 and one without it.